# NSSplitView inside tab view appears filled by first pane

Tags: cocoa, nssplitview

I have an `NSSplitView` inside an `NSTabView`. If the split view's tab is the one initially shown, it seems to work fine, but if the split view's tab is shown later instead, it appears with the first pane fully expanded and the second one collapsed. Because I want to use a thin divider for the split view, there is no way for the user to get out of this.

Returning `NO` from `splitView:canCollapseSubview:` doesn't help, even though I verified that it does get called.

As a workaround, I tried letting the split view's tab be initially shown, and then manually switching after the window is loaded (in `awakeFromNib`), but this did not fix it.

Is this a known issue with NSSplitView if it isn't initially shown? Is there a better way to apply the tab switching workaround? Or is there a better workaround?

Comment: Good. So how are you doing?

Comment: Are you saying you'd like me to state my problem differently?

Comment: haha. If you read your previous text. that was just a narration of story. There were not a single question/doubt etc. Now this is good. Sorry for saying way :p

Comment: "Collapsed" state is not the same thing as "pane size" and I didn't see you mention where you're handling the size constraints in your delegate.

Comment: I've mainly been working without a delegate, aside from trying to work around this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting around the issue by switching to [RBSplitView](http://brockerhoff.net/src/rbs.html). I also made a [fork on GitHub](https://github.com/Uncommon/RBSplitView) to update the project to work with the latest Xcode.